# How can I add a COM reference without using Visual Studio?

Tags: c#

Maybe I have to use some options on the csc command line?

Answer (score 3):

You need to generate an interop assembly for the COM library you want to use, and reference that assembly instead of the COM dll. You can generate the interop wrapper with [Aximp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ccdh774.aspx) (for ActiveX controls) or [Tlbimp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx.aspx) (for other COM components)

Comment: Hi I don't understand as in this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317881 they don't talk about Interop.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [TlbImp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx(VS.80).aspx) utility to generate an interop assembly from the COM type library and add a reference to the generated assembly with `/r` compiler switch.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Aximp.exe and Tlbimp.exe in one of my projects to generate the interop assemblies (to overcome COM component version difficulties) and a [BAT file with the calls and comments](http://pmortensen.eu/3/Vendor_COM_versioning.bat.txt) is available. The interop assemblies still need to be referenced in the Visual Studio project.